# VB support in Java 6?

Tags: java, vb6, vbscript, wikipedia, java-6

I was checking Java language history in wikipedia, and this paragraph caught my attention:

> The current version, Java SE 6
>   (December 11, 2006) — Codename Mustang
>   — is bundled with a database manager,
>   facilitates the use of scripting
>   languages (currently JavaScript using
>   Mozilla's Rhino engine) with the JVM
>   and has Visual Basic language support

What exactly does "Visual Basic language support" in this context?

Comment: Java itself has no VB support - try running it on Linux lol...

This might mean that Mozilla's Rhino engine has VBScript support, but I don't know enough about it to give you a proper answer...

Comment: Take a look at http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/index.html and http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html for some insight. Unfortunately, I am in the same position as Martin Milan. I do not know enough to give you a proper answer either.

Comment: My guess is that either it was added as a joke that and it was never removed or that someone took "Project Semplice" more serious as than it should be taken: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Semplice

Answer (score 2):

Don't believe everything you read on Wikipedia.

There are plenty of languages that run in the JVM: Groovy, Jython, JavaScript (Rhino), JRuby.   Does this mean Java has "support for Ruby"?    Depends on your perspective I guess.